# show tray in taskbar windows 10 electronjs

Tags: electron, tray

I'm using system tray of electron but when I start my app the tray hide in the dropdow of the taskbar like this image :

**(icon with S)**

[image: tray in dropdown]

I want the tray apear like this :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Windows hides icons in the notification area ([its not called "the tray"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030910-00/?p=42583)) because in the past (Windows 95 through Windows Vista) too many programs arrogantly thought they were important enough that the user should always see them there - which leads to noisy and cluttered examples like this:

[image]

To prevent this from happening and degrading the user-experience, since Windows 7 programs cannot (feasibly) promote themselves out of the "More icons..." window.

*What you should do instead* is give your users instructions on how they can tell Windows to keep an icon visible (Settings > Personalization > Taskbar > "Select which icons appear on the taskbar") themselves. But you cannot do it yourself in program code: there is no (public and documented) API for controlling this for the reasons I described above.

Answer (score -1):

Try [api/tray](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/tray)

```js
const electron = require("electron")
const app = electron.app
function createTray() {
  const tray = new electron.Tray( __dirname + 'Myfavicon.ico')
  const contextMenu = electron.Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    { label: 'Item1', type: 'radio' },
    { label: 'Item2', type: 'radio' },
    { label: 'Item3', type: 'radio', checked: true },
    { label: 'Item4', type: 'radio' }
  ])
  tray.setToolTip('This is my application.')
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu)
}

app.on("ready", createTray)
```

Comment: `electron.Tray` library is used to define a notification-area icon, but it cannot be used to make itself always be visible and not hidden in the "Show more icons" menu.